# How to get the department name in this tutorial sql query?

Tags: sql

Following the tutorial on SQL [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/joins_try_sql.php) I want to query the number of employees per department together with the department name.

I tried the following query in that tutorial:

```
SELECT count(*), dept_name
FROM employees, departments
WHERE employees.dept_id = departments.dept_id
GROUP BY departments.dept_id
```

but it returns

```
COUNT(*)    dept_name
2           NULL
2           NULL
```

instead of the expected output

```
COUNT(*)    dept_name
2           Accounting
2           Sales
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please don't use old-style implicit joins. Explicit joins are a part of ANSI-SQL for over 25 years now - there really is no reason to use old-style joins anymore.

Comment: The `group by` usage in your query is invalid standard SQL and will actually lead to an error in any self-respecting DBMS. You should find a tutorial that uses a DBMS that throws an error on invalid SQL, rather than returning some random result.

Comment: One more reason why I don't like MySql...

Comment: Why is that invalid SQL? I just want to `group by` some table attribute.

Comment: because you are selecting a column that is neither grouped nor aggregated. the database have no way of knowing what record would you like to get back on that column. MySql will arbitrarily select a record, while self-respecting database systems will throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by `dept_name` not `dept_id`

```
SELECT count(*), dept_name
FROM employees, departments
WHERE employees.dept_id = departments.dept_id
GROUP BY departments.dept_name
```

---

And you can better use `join` like `Juan Carlos Oropeza`'s answer:

```
SELECT count(*), dept_name
FROM employees JOIN departments ONemployees.dept_id = departments.dept_id
GROUP BY departments.dept_name
```

[image]

Comment: How answers using commas in the `FROM` clause get upvotes is beyond me.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff thanks, I thought it was just a simple error, and I only proposed the error point, but I didn't put forward the optimized SQL query more carefully

Answer (score 3):

First use `JOIN` instead of `WHERE`

Then you group by `dept_id` to make sure you dont have duplicate name like 2 Sales department or 2 employee with same name.

```
SELECT departments.dept_id, dept_name, count(*)
FROM employees
JOIN departments
  ON employees.dept_id = departments.dept_id
GROUP BY departments.dept_id, departments.dept_name
```